# Just starting Prolog...need help in making small Expert System

Tags: prolog, system

I have just started to use Prolog for the first time and I have to implement an Expert System.  I want to diagnose someone as having fear of the dark if he/she cannot seem to see things in the dark and seem to feel unprotected in the dark. Here is my code for this scenario:

```
fear(dark) :- positive(cantSee), positive(unprotectedInDark).
```

However, I don't think I am sure that this is the right code to work. Here is my code to make positive(X) "yes":

```
positive(X) :- ask(X, yes).
ask(X, yes) :- write(X), write('? '), read(yes).
```

Likewise, here is my code for negative(X):

```
negative(X) :- ask(X, no).
ask(X, no) :- write(X), write('? '), read(no).
```

Is this the right code to my problem above? Also, how can I make my expert system 'remember' an answer? This code was in my mind, but I don't think this one works:

```
remember(X, yes) :- assert(ask(X, yes)).
remember(X, no) :- assert(ask(X, no)).
```

Comment: By remember, you mean that you want your program to remember it while it is being executed or even after you close the file and execute it again?

Comment: By remember, I mean say that if I say yes to a question, the system keeps the answer as yes and it cannot change it. For instance, once the answer is yes, I cannot change it to a no.

Comment: An Expert System seems like an aggressive first project for just learning Prolog. If you don't want it to overwrite an answer once written, you can just check to see if it's been asserted already and don't retract and assert a new one. Or is there a reason that won't work for your situation?

Comment: You may find an expert system shell such as [CLIPS](http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/) to be a better match than Prolog for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

maybe ask/2 should check before if the question has already been answered.

```
:- dynamic remember/2.

ask(What, YN) :- remember(What, YN), !.
ask(What, YN) :- write(What), write(?),
     read(YN), /* should validate user'answer */,
     assertz(remember(What, YN)).
```